# How to troubleshoot SpringBoot POM issues

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud

As the question says, I have the below POM for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.wipro.microservices.eureka</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka</name>
    <description>Eureka Microservice for Assignment</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This POM is letting me compile the Microservice without any problem on machine 1. But on machine 2, I am getting error during build stating that

```
Dependency org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server:${project.version} not found
```

I tried few changes and changing the Hoxton version from SR3 to SR8 is letting the project build.

What kind of discrepancies cause these builds to fail on one and pass on the other. How does on troubleshoot these issues.

Any pointers will help as I am running into the trivial problems lately.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The error message implies that the definition in your pom is given: `<artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>` plus `<version>${project.version}</version>` but the posted pom shows something different... so you having a difference between the two machines..using different branches not up to date ?

Comment: if you are using intellij as an editor, you can use this plugin it will help you a lot

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper